# Javascript no captura formulario

Tags: javascript, html, html5, formularios

tengo el que realizar un formulario en el cual debo realizar ciertas validaciones, pero quitando eso me ocurre algo super raro con el compilador. Cuando llamo a un evento onclick en dos de los botones me tira un error de que la función no está definida pero... si lo hago haciendole el evento de ventana me pilla el botón... Qué puede pasar y por qué me pasa. Estoy un 99% seguro que mi código no está mal. Adjunto código y también captura del error.

Fotografías:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código:**

```js
function validar(){
    
  console.log("validar");

}
function anadir(){

  console.log("añadir");

}
function comprar(){
  console.log("comprar");
}
```

```html
<form id="formDatosPersonales" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
    <div>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="user_nombre" placeholder="Rellena el campo..." required>
        <!--  -->
        <label for="apellido">Apellidos:</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="user_apellido" placeholder="Rellena el campo..." required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Rellena el campo..." required>
        <!--  -->
        <label for="pwd">Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="user_pwd" placeholder="Rellena el campo...">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="compra">
            <span style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;">Selecciona los articulos a comprar</span>
        </label>
        <select id="compra" name="compra">
            <optgroup label="equipacion">
                <option value="20">Camiseta</option>
                <option value="10">pantalones</option>
                <option value="5">medias</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Entrada">
                <option value="100">Fondo Sur</option> 
                <option value="100">Fondo norte</option>
                <option value="200">Tribuna Cubierta</option>
                <option value="50">lateral Derecho</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Tour">
                <option value="10">Tour normal</option>
                <option value="25">Tour con guia</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="numero" required>
        <input type="text" id="suma" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="comentarios">Dejanos tus comentarios:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="comentarios" name="user_comentarios" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="button">
        <input type="button" id="validar" name="validar" value="Validar" onclick="validar()"/>
        <input type="button" id="añadir" name="añadir" value="Añadir" onclick="anadir()"/>
        <input type="button" id="comprar" name="comprar" value="Comprar" onclick="comprar()">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso te sucede porque la mayoría de navegadores modernos tienden a importar los **ID** de los elementos **HTML** dentro del **JavaScript namespace global** por lo que que cuando tratas de hacer un `onclick="validar()"` el navegador piensa que estás tratando de acceder al elemento `id="validar"` y al no tratarse de una función te suelta el error que nos nuestras.

Una solución sería cambiar el nombre de tus funciones para que no coincida con el de los **ID** de tus elementos.

```js
function validar_funcion(){  
  console.log("validar");
}

function anadir_funcion(){
  console.log("añadir");
}

function comprar_funcion(){
  console.log("comprar");
}
```

```html
<form id="formDatosPersonales" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
    <div>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="user_nombre" placeholder="Rellena el campo..." required>
        <!--  -->
        <label for="apellido">Apellidos:</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="user_apellido" placeholder="Rellena el campo..." required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Rellena el campo..." required>
        <!--  -->
        <label for="pwd">Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="user_pwd" placeholder="Rellena el campo...">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="compra">
            <span style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;">Selecciona los articulos a comprar</span>
        </label>
        <select id="compra" name="compra">
            <optgroup label="equipacion">
                <option value="20">Camiseta</option>
                <option value="10">pantalones</option>
                <option value="5">medias</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Entrada">
                <option value="100">Fondo Sur</option> 
                <option value="100">Fondo norte</option>
                <option value="200">Tribuna Cubierta</option>
                <option value="50">lateral Derecho</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Tour">
                <option value="10">Tour normal</option>
                <option value="25">Tour con guia</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="numero" required>
        <input type="text" id="suma" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="comentarios">Dejanos tus comentarios:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="comentarios" name="user_comentarios" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="button">
        <input type="button" id="validar" name="validar" value="Validar" onclick="validar_funcion()"/>
        <input type="button" id="añadir" name="añadir" value="Añadir" onclick="anadir_funcion()"/>
        <input type="button" id="comprar" name="comprar" value="Comprar" onclick="comprar_funcion()">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Otra solución es intentar evitar añadir los event handlers en el el HTML y usar `getElementById(...).addEventListener('click', ....)`, dejando el código más limpio

Comment: La manera que comenta @PabloLozano es la óptima. Así independizas el **HTML** del **JS** y si en un futuro necesitas que tus botones llamen a otras funciones no tienes que modificar el **HTML**, solamente el **JS**.